# CSS effects hindering visibility on mobile version

Tags: html, css

I have a small wordpress website for a think tank i'm part of, Blue-europe.eu.
The website uses the theme *The Gem* and *elementor*, in addition with other WP plugin that are not related to visual effect.
My problem lays with the mobile version : each content (image and text) that uses a CSS effect (fade in right, etc) doesn't work and does not even show any form of text.
Is there a possibility to de-activate all those CSS effect for images and texts, but only on the mobile version?

Regards
Brian

Answer (score 0):

In the elementor menu advanced -> Motion Effects you have the option to choose effect based on device.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i didn't notice it!

Comment: @Blue Europe No problem. I had to double check  it  myself. Pleas check the answer resolved if you are pleased with the answer.

Comment: Well i've tried it and it doesn't work. Is there a CSS code that i may add in the theme maybe?

Comment: I visited the link and it seems like there are more things that are broken with the responsive layout. Things overlap and disappear, most of those things shouldn't be a problem in elementor. 
It seems to happen when you reload the page, then all the text disappear. If I clear the catch through devtools->application->cookies it reloads just fine in all formats mobile and desktop, but as soon as i reload again everything disappear.